# Combotree in javascript (jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a component which enable display tree in combo (select).
Something like that: http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php

But this component doesn't allow import JSON directly, only from file.

It works in that way:

```
$('#cc').combotree({  
        url:'tree_data.json'  
    });
```

I need (pseudocode):

```
$('#cc').combotree({  
        data:'[{"id":1,"text":"City","children":[{"id":11,"text":"Wyoming","children":[{"id":111,"text":"Albin"}]}]}]' 
    });
```

Or (pseudocode):

```
$('#cc').combotree({  
        data:'<?php $json_string; ?>'  
    });
```

Is it possible? Or maybe do you know any components which enable to do that?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$obj = json_encode('['.json_encode($objects).']');
$jquery_obj = str_replace(",\\\"name\\\":", ",\\\"text\\\":", $obj);
print $jquery_obj;

?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var jq_data = $.parseJSON(<? print $jquery_obj; ?>);

$('#cc').combotree({  

    animate:true,
    data:jq_data
});

});

</script>
<select id="cc" class="easyui-combotree"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `data` parameter? The documentation says it should work. (Give the data as an array, not a string.) You can also give the data as an `ul` list. Check the documentation for `tree`.

Comment: Yes, I can give the data as an `ul` list to `tree` but not to `combotree`.
I tried the `data` parameter with poor result.
If you have any idea maybe paste here some code, please.